# Error 002061 - Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' reported error: Authentication requires secure connection

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, database-replication

MySQL version - 8.0.23 on RDS
I am replicating my local database to AWS RDS MySQL instance. But I am getting this error:

```
2021-11-11T22:43:09.091947Z 378 [ERROR] [MY-010584] [Repl] Slave I/O for channel '': error connecting to master 'replicator@localhost:3306' - retry-time: 60 retries: 1 message: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' reported error: Authentication requires secure connection. Error_code: MY-002061
```

My RDS slave status:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: localhost
                  Master_User: replicator
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: DESKTOP-7DL3FOM-bin.000010
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 700
               Relay_Log_File: relaylog.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: DESKTOP-7DL3FOM-bin.000010
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: innodb_memcache.cache_policies,innodb_memcache.config_options,mysql.plugin,mysql.rds_configuration,mysql.rds_history,mysql.rds_monitor,mysql.rds_replication_status,mysql.rds_sysinfo
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 700
              Relay_Log_Space: 1166
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 2061
                Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'replicator@localhost:3306' - retry-time: 60 retries: 1 message: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' reported error: Authentication requires secure connection.
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 0
                  Master_UUID:
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp: 211111 23:08:40
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
       Master_public_key_path:
        Get_master_public_key: 0
            Network_Namespace:
```

I have tried changing my master db user password format to mysql native password. But it is not helping. What should I do to get through this problem?

Comment: caching_sha2_password requires SSL for communication. https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/rds-mysql-8-default-auth-plugin-is-mysql_native_password/

use default plugin mysql_native_password  if you are not using SSL .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MySQL Server 8.0.11

> caching_sha2_password

is used as the default authentication method. Still, you can use the plugin

> mysql_native_password

to log in with the old method.

For more. Please go through this [link](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/rds-mysql-8-default-auth-plugin-is-mysql_native_password/)

Answer (score 6):

please run change master command with GET_MASTER_PUBLIC_KEY=1

Answer (score 5):

In did mysql replication databases master / slave. I also had a mistake and I ignored it for a while, like this

```
CHANGE MASTER TO GET_MASTER_PUBLIC_KEY=1;
```

Answer (score 2):

As written in the other answers use `GET_MASTER_PUBLIC_KEY=1`.
Full connect string is:

```
CHANGE REPLICATION SOURCE TO
SOURCE_HOST='master_ip_number',
SOURCE_USER='replica_user',
SOURCE_PASSWORD='p4zzw0rd',
SOURCE_LOG_FILE='binlog.000007',
SOURCE_LOG_POS=7777,
GET_MASTER_PUBLIC_KEY=1;
```

The `SOURCE_LOG_FILE` and `SOURCE_LOG_POS` you will get from the master with the command:

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS;
```